# Generating an encoded string from a bit value in swift 4.2

Tags: swift, binary, bitwise-operators, bit

First off, sorry if this is not named or labeled properly, or doesn't make sense - I am very new to the topic and could really use some guidance.

I need to generate a base-36 encoded string from a bit XX-bit value.

I am given precise instructions for each bit in the sequence. For instance:

- Bits 42-39 are `0b000`
- Bit 30 is ON
- Bits 27 - 0 are `0b1010010100b11000101101000100101000110`

and so on.

So far, I've been trying to aggregate the bit data as an array:

```
let array : [UInt32] = [0b10100, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0b11000101101000100101000110]
```

Can anyone please advise on how to extract the bit sequence from it (`0b1010010100b11000101101000100101000110`) and how to later on encode it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more examples?

Answer (score 0):

Could do this:

```
let bitValue = 0b11000101101000100101000110
let digitsNumber = 26
var remain = bitValue
var boolArray = [Bool]()
for _ in 0..<digitsNumber {
    let r = remain % 2
    let bitSet = r == 1
    boolArray.insert(bitSet, at: 0)
    remain = (remain - r) / 2
}

print(boolArray)
```

and get:
[true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false]